# How to make backround image transparent?

Tags: 3d-view, image

How can I make backround image transparent?

Now it is white and it is harr to understand where is my model and where image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the image

Go to object data properties

[image]

Check `Use Alpha` and set the transparency